# xcode autoadjust for javascript

Tags: javascript, xcode

I use xcode to edit javascript code. Everything is Ok, except the case below

```
var MYClass = cc.Layer.extend({ //a press return key here

    a:0,
    init:function () {
        this.a=-1;
    }
});
```

but autoadjust always set it as:

```
var MYClass = cc.Layer.extend({ //press return key here


                              a:0,
                              init:function () {
                              this.a=-1; 

                              }
                              });
```

Thus I have to adjust code manually.
It look likes symbol '(' and ')' causes the result
I checked the preference text editing option, but no any solution, 
Maybe it needs User defaults command.

You comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Xcode preferences and select Text Editing. Then click the `Indentation` tab, and uncheck `Automatically indent based on syntax`.